# How to use Callback with Static data ( use )?

Tags: php

is there way to use Callback with "use" keyword without crashing PHP script?

php - **7.4.23**

```
public function map(callable $callback) {
    $keys = array_keys($this->items);
    $items = array_map($callback, $this->items, $keys); // CRASH PART 

    return new static(array_combine($keys, $items));
}

Collection($data)->map(
            function (\stdClass $dbData, int $shippingId) use ($class) {
                return '';
            }
)
```

it THROW "**[NOTICE] Undefined offset: 2**", it should be ignored but for some reason it kills whole PHP script, even with custom "**set_error_handler**"

Comment: First off, I'm assuming that you actually store the the posted closure in the variable `$callback`, like `$callback = function ($dbData) use ($class) {...};`? Then, `$dbData->test` won't work since you're passing in an array `[]` and not an object in your `array_map()`. As a general note, you should _always_ include details about what actually happens. Post all error messages etc.

Comment: no, i pass it by argument to another function with type of "callable"

Comment: Then please post _all_ relevant code since the above code makes no sense then. All it does is creating an anonymous function without storing it somewhere and then you use `array_map()` with a, for us, completely unknown variable as callback.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson post is edited but still in pseudo code

Comment: You're still trying to use an array as an object though, which will never work. And in your example, you've defined `$class` as a string but are trying to use it as an object instance inside the callback. You're also missing the second argument when calling `runCallback()`

Comment: Post your actual code instead of pseudo code that contains a bunch of other issues.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but "$class::handle($dbData->test)" should be "dynamicData:::handle($dbData->test)" its valid for PHP or am i wrong ? or miss something ?, thanks

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct regarding `$class`, but you still have the other issues (like missing second argument, using an array as an object). If you have a specific issue with a piece of code, you should show us that specific code instead of writing some pseudo code. The posted code will definitely throw errors, but not the one you're getting.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated question, only return is deleted from callback :)